# :hover selector works but :focus does not

Tags: css, angular

I am using Angular 4 and I have a selected for a `mat-card` of `:hover` which seems fine. I have added a `click event` to the `mat-card` and when clicked I want the background to stay the same color as the hover until another item has been clicked.

```
  <mat-card>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
      <div class="card-label" fxFlex.xl="50" fxFlex.lg="50" fxFlex.md="50" fxFlex.sm="50" fxFlex.xs="100">
        <span>Version Number:</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-value" fxFlex.xl="50" fxFlex.lg="50" fxFlex.md="50" fxFlex.sm="50" fxFlex.xs="100">
        <span>{{version.versionNumber}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
      <div class="card-label" fxFlex.xl="50" fxFlex.lg="50" fxFlex.md="50" fxFlex.sm="50" fxFlex.xs="100">
        <span>User:</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-value" fxFlex.xl="50" fxFlex.lg="50" fxFlex.md="50" fxFlex.sm="50" fxFlex.xs="100">
        <span>{{version.user}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
      <div class="card-label" fxFlex.xl="50" fxFlex.lg="50" fxFlex.md="50" fxFlex.sm="50" fxFlex.xs="100">
        <span>Created Date:</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-value" fxFlex.xl="50" fxFlex.lg="50" fxFlex.md="50" fxFlex.sm="50" fxFlex.xs="100">
        <span>{{version.createdDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
      <div class="card-label" fxFlex.xl="50" fxFlex.lg="50" fxFlex.md="50" fxFlex.sm="50" fxFlex.xs="100">
        <span>Start Date:</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-value" fxFlex.xl="50" fxFlex.lg="50" fxFlex.md="50" fxFlex.sm="50" fxFlex.xs="100">
        <span>{{version.startDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-card>
```

The CSS:

```
mat-card:hover {
    background-color: rgba(42, 63, 84, .2);
}

mat-card:focus {
    background: blue;
}
```

Like i said the hover works fine but the :focus does not.

Comment: Clicked and Focus are two different things. Are you sure `mat-card` is a focusable element? What happens when you add a `tabIndex` to `mat-card`?

Comment: @chazsolo Yes! This worked thanks for your help, it went totally over my head.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that only `<input>` elements can have the focus event occur to them ([see here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp)). You could create a function that adds a class with the desired color when you click on the `mat-card` element or a `<div>` surrounding it, then execute another function that removes the class when the other item[s] are clicked. Or use .toggleClass() from JQuery, which I think is included in jqLite with Angular.

Answer (score 1):

Yes because you can just apply the focus event on elements you can focus on. This is for example an input field. You can't give :focus on a div container.

```css
#somediv:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

#someinput:focus {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="somediv">Sometext</div>
<input id="someinput">
```

Look for that code. Click in the input and then the :focus will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this outside of css. add a click event to the host and add a class to the host element.

```
@componet(
host: {
   "(click)": "onClick($event)"
})
export class Foo {
  @HostBinding('class.active') isActive: boolean = false; 
  onClick(e){
   this.isActive = !this.isActive;
  }
}
```